# Solving $\dot{x}^2+\frac{k}{m}x^2-\frac{k}{m}x^2_{max}=0$ from a spring oscillator problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

In my mechanics class we had a differential equation arise from a spring oscillator via its energy ($x^2_{max}$ is some constant maximum length) :

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2}kx^2_{max}&=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2\\\frac{k}{m}x^2_{max}&=\dot{x}^2+\frac{k}{m}x^2\\\end{align}$$

So we have $\dot{x}^2+\frac{k}{m}x^2-\frac{k}{m}x^2_{max}=0$ from this. I've been having some trouble solving this and WFA wasn't any help either. In the lecture my professor took the derivative and solved from there :

$$\begin{align}2\ddot{x}\dot{x}+2\frac{k}{m}x\dot{x}&=0\\\implies\ddot{x}+\frac{k}{m}x&=0\end{align}$$

In the end this would mean $x=x_{max}\cos(\omega t+\phi)$, but I'm still really confused about the technique of just taking the derivative here to solve. I thought maybe it's something like $y=x^2\implies\dot{y}=2x\dot{x}$ in disguise, but it doesn't really simplify once I rearrange for $\dot{x}^2$. How can I understand this?

Comment: It's OK to differentiate two sides even though additional solutions may be introduced. You can also express $x'$ in terms of $x$ right away and get two first order separable equations.

Comment: If $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$, then $f'(x)=g'(x)$ for all $x$ as well. (One possible loophole here is if the domain was something goofy, e.g., functions only defined on rationals. But those kinds of pathologies are not relevant in this context.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe moving away from the dot notation (which I have always hated but is sometimes necessary) may be helpful...

$$\frac{1}{2}kx^2_{max}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2$$
$$\therefore\frac{k}{m}x_{max}^2=v^2+\frac{k}{m}x^2$$

Applying the $\frac{d}{dt}$ operator on both sides of our equation yields;

$$0=\frac{d}{dt}(v\cdot v)+\frac{k}{m}\bigg[\frac{d}{dt}(x\cdot x)\bigg]$$

Which, by the product rule, gives us;

$$0=2(v' \cdot v)+2\frac{k}{m}(x'\cdot x)$$

$$\therefore0=2(x'' \cdot x')+2\frac{k}{m}(x'\cdot x)=2x'\bigg[x''+\frac{k}{m}x\bigg]$$

Now, this equality must hold for all $t$ but we know that $2x'$ is not equal to $0$ at all times. Therefore we must have;

$$x''+\frac{k}{m}x=0 $$

Comment: and we’re always allowed to just take the derivative? Are there any conditions that need to be satisfied?

Comment: Because we differentiated we need to supply two initial conditions ( one extra) instead of one condition  for full solution.

Comment: @AnthonyML You are free to apply the derivative as many times as you want but you will often lose information (namely the relevant constants). So you will need additional initial conditions to recover the desired behavior.